# Exception while adding new route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I added new Route in Register Route.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.wdgt/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("ChartImg.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.Ignore("{*pathInfo}", new { pathInfo = @"^.*(ChartImg.axd)$" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc");

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "DefaultWithTenantCode",
   url: "{tenantcode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, tenantcode = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   );
```

Now I tried to access the below url, I am getting the following exception.
localhost:53643/Account/LogOn

**Exception:**
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The controller for path '/Account/LogOn' was not found or does not implement IController.
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)}

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have declared 2 routes that will both match so .NET routing won't be able to tell the difference between them. When you navigate to `/Account/Logon`, it is matching the `DefaultWithTenantCode` route instead of the `Default` route with the following route values.

```
tenantCode = "Account"
controller = "LogOn"
action = "Index"
id = ""
```

One way to get out of this scenario - add some kind of identifier to the route so it will know when you are passing a tenantcode.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultWithTenantCode",
    url: "tenant-code-{tenantcode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, tenantcode = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This will expect a URL like `/tenant-code-21/Tenant/Index/` when matching the `DefaultWithTenantCode` route. If it doesn't start with the tenant code, it will use the `Default` route.

Another option is to make all of the parameters required when passing a tenantcode.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultWithTenantCode",
    url: "{tenantcode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
        );
```

This will mean it won't ever match the `DefaultWithTenantCode` route unless all 4 parameters are passed explicitly.